# WooCommerce: custom function to manage stock of variable products at the individual attribute level

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I create a custom function to manage stock at the individual attribute level?

#### For example

**Product:** t-shirt signed by me

- **Attribute 1:** Size - small | medium | large
- **Attribute 2:** Marker Color - blue | red | black

In cases like these, you'd want to manage stock by attribute 1 only. It makes no sense to manage stock by attribute 2 also.

#### What I've Tried

Since I'm just beginning with custom WordPress functions, I don't know where to start. It seems that a custom stock reduction function that filters by SKU could work, but I've searched and can't find any examples to work from.

**Note:** My actual use case for this is classes offered on different days with different payment options through WooCommerce Subscriptions:

**Product:** Learning Seminar

- **Attribute 1:** Class Day - Mon at 1 p.m. | Wed at 10 a.m.
- **Attribute 2:** Payment Options - Single Payment | 2 Payments | 4 Payments

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for this? Regards

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super old question, but I've had several clients ask for this type of *attribute-based* stock management, so I ended up developing a plugin for it: [Attribute Stock for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/attribute-stock-for-woocommerce/)

The idea is that you can set stock directly on attribute terms which will get deducted appropriately when matching products are purchased.

**For example:** You can set your stock on each of the `Size` attribute terms and disable stock management for the product/variations so that stock is only managed at the attribute level.